# does CSSOM and DOM construction happens on parallel threads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I was looking online for this answer for long time . But got no concrete answers to this question . I want to know how each process works in rendering (i.e. using multiple threads or single threads)

Comment: I guess there is no concrete answer, it could change at any point in a new version, and that's because it does not really matter for any other component. Why do you care?

Comment: Could you please share the non-concrete answers that you already found?

Comment: @Bergi i agree that there would not be a concrete example, especially that this is an implementation detail for each browser, however in practice there is no way to create CSSOM without dom being completely built and ready, because styles calculations needs css selectors, and without a ready dom, css selectors are completely meaningless. But who knows, things might change in the future, and the web might introduce new html/css syntax that enables  certain css styles to be applied in parallel with dom parsing.

Comment: sorry i meant a concrete answer

Comment: @ehab Parsing CSS, creating the CSSOM objects  and doing style calculations are different things and might or might not happen in parallel to building the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi css parsing and cssom creation might be done without the dom - though in practice it wont be so beneficial because css selectors might have a lof of info about nodes that wont be relevant any more. However style calculations need the dom to be ready for sure afaik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to render the page the browser has to [do multiple complex steps](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/inside-browser-part3), in generality these steps are : parsing/loading, style calculation, creating layout tree, paint, and then finally [Rasterisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) ( in this step the browser takes the results that was generated from all the previous steps, and turn that info into colored pixels that are drawn on your screen).

In short, in the parsing/loading step, the main thread starts parsing the html, and creating the dom tree, and when it reach  - or even peak about - external resources it starts loading these resources in a background network thread(s). unless you defer loading these resources, the browser still needs to parse/execute them before going to next step.

In the style calculation step, the browser determines styles for each node, this also happens in the main thread, and needs to happen after dom has been created. styles can not be calculated in parallel with dom parsing, because styles need to be calculated based on css selectors, and css selectors are meaningless without the dom tree being completely structured and ready to be read - up till the point where that style declaration appears.

After styles are calculated, browsers start creating layout tree - you could think of the layout tree as a huge rectangular grid created of smaller rectangles, where the browser knows where every element is positioned and in which small rectangle in the whole grid, along with x,y coordinates, and bounding boxes size. This step also happens in the main thread, and can not be parallel with style calculation, because it needs dom and cssom as inputs in order to produce its output.

After that painting comes, also happens in main thread, and again needs the previous results as its input, and so can not be parallel with layout creation, in this step the browser creates painting structures for the whole layout tree.

From here the browser commit all this information to the [Compositor thread](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/compositor-thread-architecture), this is where things in parallel start to happen, the compositor thread knows how to take the layout tree, and composite that into frames that you see. The compositor thread is extremely smart, it knows how to prioritise and parallelize workload, it sends its workload to different rasterisation threads, and these are responsible for giving you the colored pixels that are drawn in your screen.

The Compositor thread is not only used for the initial render, but also used anytime the main thread wants to render stuff. In fact when you are scrolling, you are scrolling on the compositor thread, and recently chromium has been moving a lot of stuff to the compositor thread, so that even if the main thread gets blocked then ui still behaves smoothly. If you want to learn more about the compositor thread you can also see [this link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/how_cc_works.md) (along with the one i [previously shared](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/compositor-thread-architecture))

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. So acc. to what i read in multiple articles and acc to my understanding . I thought of this as : browser gets first Byte it start parsing and building DOM when it encounters CSS resource it fetches the same and it keeps building CSSOM in parallel and then at some point it merges both CSSOM and DOM to render tree.

Comment: No its not like that, everything in the browser almost happens in the main thread - except for javascript workers, and internal threads that are used for garbage collection, or audio, or other internals. The main thread starts parsing html, when it reaches a resource like inline css, it parses it, it creates an internal structure that makes it easy to act on this css later, a cssom internal representation might be created at this point, but only exposed later when dom is ready. style calculations only happens after dom is completely ready, also happens in main thread.

Comment: @Devinder style calculations need to happen for sure after dom is ready, because it makes no sense other wise, obviously you can start doing that on a snapshot of the dom but that does not make sense on initial  rendering, since dom will change and all these style calculations will be thrown away and needs to be recalculated.  this is why on initial rendering style calculations happens after dom becomes completely ready